# Non-virtual overloaded member functions

Tags: c++, overloading

This code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int one() {
    std::cout << "oneA" << std::endl;
  }
  int devone() {
    one();
  }
};

struct B : A {
  int one() {
    std::cout << "oneB" << std::endl;
  }
};
int main() {
  B b;
  b.devone();
}
```

prints **oneA**

I don't understand why.
I know that if I use virtual functions **oneB** is printed, but why not in the above code examples. No pointers or references are used, why do I need to declare the function virtual?

Comment: Actually there is a pointer.  It is just hidden from you.  Remember all member functions have a `this` pointer.

Comment: The type of `this` inside `A::devone` is `A *`, therefore `A::one` gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No pointers or references are used, why do I need to declare the function virtual?

You are wrong, this code:

```
 int A::devone() {
     one();
 }
```

is equal to:

```
int A::devone() {
  this->one();
}
```

so pointer is used, and to resolve proper function at runtime you have to use `virtual` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not declare `one` as virtual, then it will not have an entry in `A`s vtable.  If there is no vtable entry in `A`, that means the only `one` it knows about is its own.  So when you call `one` from `A::devone`, logically the only function it *can* call is `A::one`.

Answer (score 0):

It outputs "oneA" because you are calling A::devone(), which in turn calls A::one().
Because A::one() is NOT virtual, even if you have a B instance, the base A class one() method will be called anyway.

If you add

```
  int devone() {
    one();
  }
```

to the B class, B::one() method would be called instead.